# comma seperated string used as column of a table

Tags: postgresql

I have a string parameter in function . The same needs to be used as concatenation of table column.

I tried concat, regexp_substr and various other techniques but it didn't worked

```
do $$

  declare
      v_11 varchar(100):='col_1,col_2';
      v_timeseries varchar(1000);
  begin
      execute format('
        select case 
          when 1=1 then
            concat(regexp_substr(%I, ''[^,]+'', 1, 1),regexp_substr(%I, ''[^,]+'', 1, 2))
          else
            ''0''
          end as data
        from grp_tab limit 1', v_11, v_11) 
      into v_timeseries;

      raise info 'v_timeseries %',v_timeseries;
end $$;
```

Expected result:

```
select col_1||col_2 from grp_tab;
```

but the actual result which I am getting

```
Output: col_1Col_2
```

We need the actual values to be concatenated.

Note: Columns values to be concatenated may differ in `runtime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `split_part`. Note that it may be extracted and used as an argument outside the format string.

```
knayak=# create table grp_tab ( col_1 text, col_2 text);
CREATE TABLE
knayak=# insert into grp_tab(col_1,col_2) values('TEXT1', 'TEXT2');
INSERT 0 1


knayak=# do $$
knayak$# declare
knayak$#  v_11 varchar(100):='col_1,col_2';
knayak$#   v_timeseries varchar(1000);
knayak$#   begin
knayak$#  execute format('select case when 1=1 then %I||%I else ''0''
knayak$#        end as data
knayak$#  from grp_tab limit 1',split_part(v_11,',',1),split_part(v_11,',',2))
knayak$# into v_timeseries;
knayak$# raise info 'v_timeseries %',v_timeseries;
knayak$# end $$;
INFO:  v_timeseries TEXT1TEXT2
DO
```

If you do not have additional commas in between, you may simply replace the commas with concatenated string and pass a single argument to format. `%s` is used which formats the argument value as a simple string

```
do $$
declare
 v_11 varchar(100):='col_1,col_2';
 v_cols text := replace(v_11,',', '||');
 v_timeseries varchar(1000);
  begin
 execute format('select case when 1=1 then %s else ''0'' 
       end as data
 from grp_tab limit 1' , v_cols) 
into v_timeseries;
raise info 'v_timeseries %',v_timeseries;
end $$;
```

Comment: Thank u so much for the reply. 
In case we don't know how many columns would be there..how should i proceed?
For example: IF value is v_11 := 'col1,col2,col3....coln)
then how will i get the same output in runtime.

Comment: @Satish Mahant : I think the second option might work for you

Comment: I tried the same and it is working now.Many thanks to you. :)

Comment: I need last help :

Comment: do $$
declare
v_out text;
v_inp text := '{"id" : "1"'||trim(col1)||'}';
begin
execute format('select %s from tab',v_inp) into v_out;
raise info 'out: %',v_out;
exception
when others then
raise info  'error mssg %',sqlerrm;
end $$;

Getting Error: column "col1" does not exist

Actual: table and colmn both exist and the query is working fine

select '{"id" : "1"'||trim(col1)||'}' from tab;

Comment: @SatishMahant : This answers your original question. If you have further queries, you should ask them as a fresh question. Comments are not meant for questions in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Ohk Sorry..I will ask as a fresh